# IIS Net core http 500.30 issue

Tags: windows, iis, server

HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Common solutions to this issue:
•The application failed to start
•The application started but then stopped
•The application started but threw an exception during startup

Troubleshooting steps:
• Check the system event log for error messages
• Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
• Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit:  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265

im using asp.net core..

I Tried webconfig like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xxxxx.WebUI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 6b398a99-cb3a-4437-951d-799ba31b5ccb-->
```

but i can't get out the HTTP Error 500.30 does anyone knows how can i do it?

Comment: You should check the actual error message in Windows event log, but a report can also reveal common causes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the correct version of asp.net core SDK and runtime from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core).
Install the appropriate one according to your computer.
[image]
If you have installed it correctly but it still cannot work, you can set

```
hostingModel="outofprocess"
```

Comment: Do the application pools and folders have sufficient permissions to read applications? Or you can set stdoutLogEnabled="true" to check log file.